# Error while creating Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-8

I am trying to make a spring boot application and connect it with mongodb in a multi module project. But I am not able to setup the springboot properly. I am getting error when I run the application.

Project Structure:

```
--MainModule

------SubModule

-----------Controller(UsersController.java)

-----------Main(UserApplication.java)

-----------Model(Users.java and Address.java)

-----------Repository(UsersRepository.java)

-----------Service(UsersService.java)
```

UserApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"repository","model","service"})
@EnableMongoRepositories("repository.UsersRepository")
public class UsersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UsersApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UsersController.java

```
 @RestController
    class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create" ,  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Users create(@RequestBody Users user) {

        return usersService.createUser(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/get/{id}")
    public Optional<Users> getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        return usersService.getById(id);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Users> getAll(){
        return usersService.getAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping("/update/{id}")
    public Users update(@RequestBody Users user) {
        Users u = usersService.updateUser(user);
        return u;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        usersService.deleteUser(id);
        return "Deleted "+id;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String err(){return "error";}
}
```

UsersRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, Integer> {


}
```

UsersService.java

```
@Service
public class UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    //create a user
    public Users createUser(Users user)
    {
        return usersRepository.save(user);
    }

    //retrive all users
    public List<Users> getAll()
    {
        return usersRepository.findAll();

    }

    //retrive a user
    public Optional<Users> getById(int id)
    {
        return usersRepository.findById(id);
    }

    //update a user
    public Users updateUser(Users user)
    {
        Optional<Users> u = usersRepository.findById(user.getId());
        if(u.isPresent())
        {
            u.get().setName(user.getName());
            u.get().setAge(user.getAge());
            u.get().setAddress(user.getAddress());
        }
        return usersRepository.save(u.get());
    }

    //delete a user
    public void deleteUser(int id)
    {
        Optional<Users> user = usersRepository.findById(id);
        if(user.isPresent())
        {
            usersRepository.delete(user.get());
        }

    }
}
```

Users.java

```
@Document
public class Users {

    @Id
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    Address address;
    public Users(int id, String name, int age, Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

    private String mainAddress;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    private long pincode;
    public Address()
    {

    }
    public Address(String mainAddress) {
        super();
        this.mainAddress = mainAddress;
        this.lat = 0;
        this.lon = 0;
        this.pincode = 000000;
    }

    public Address(String mainAddress, double lat, double lon, long pincode) {
        super();
        this.mainAddress = mainAddress;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
    public String getMainAddress() {
        return mainAddress;
    }
    public void setMainAddress(String mainAddress) {
        this.mainAddress = mainAddress;
    }
    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(int lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }
    public void setLon(int lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
    public long getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(long pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

}
```

Error

```
019-03-18 10:55:21.020  WARN 14486 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-03-18 10:55:21.024  INFO 14486 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-18 10:55:21.044  INFO 14486 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-18 10:55:21.148 ERROR 14486 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field usersRepository in service.UsersService required a bean of type 'repository.UsersRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'repository.UsersRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Place `UsersApplication` directly in the `submodule` package and not in a subpackage. Then remove all annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`. This will detect all your components automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableMongoRepositories` takes `basePackages` as a parameter. It lists packages to scan for repositories, try with this:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories("repository")
```

Comment: it worked but the issue is in the component scan I have mention the packages explicitly

Comment: This must be repeated for mongo repos. Maybe not passing any parameter could work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
--MainModule

------SubModule

------Main(UserApplication.java)

-----------Controller(UsersController.java)

-----------Model(Users.java and Address.java)

-----------Repository(UsersRepository.java)

-----------Service(UsersService.java)
```

Comment: If the UserApplication is not in any package hten it gives the erroor saying that there might be a component scan in your base package

Comment: @AnubhavJha Don't use default package.